Steering clunk - 2012 Audi Q5
My wife's 2012 Audi Q5 has recently started making a 'clunk' noise/feeling when turning the steering wheel. It happens both when moving & when stationary and the 'clunk' occurs roughly every 180 degrees when turning across the full range of movement.
It doesn't feel like there's any significant play in the steering, and the wheels follow the movement of the steering wheel without any hesitation or trouble.
What's the most likely culprit here - u-joint in the steering column maybe?
Update - when I was looking at the car yesterday it was warm after having just been driven.
This morning when it's cold, the clunk cannot be heard, and the feeling is significantly reduced, so it seems that temperature makes a big difference to the symptoms.
Further update: lubricating the lower u-joint where the steering column connects to the rack greatly improved the symptoms, so I've ordered a new lower steering column (since the u-joint by itself is not individually replaceable).

I have a Q5 S Line 2015 2ltr TDI and I am experiencing exactly the same problems, also when warm, but not cold.
I’ve just checked all the bushes and suspension components, which are okay ,but it definitely is coming from somewhere deep underneath the steering column, so it looks as if it is the same problem as yours. I have booked it in at my local dealer in the next 10 days so will let you know how it goes.

I replaced the lower steering column with its permanently attached u-joints (both upper & lower), and this has resolved the symptoms (although there is now a new problem which I'll describe in a new question).
